# Is the user list (sorted by time) bugged?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, users

If you take a look at the user list over reputation [sorted by "Year"](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=year), and then [again by "All"](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all) why does the list change? Considering this site has only been around for a few days, shouldn't the same order by shown? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list "by year" refers to all reputation earned in the year. The "all" refers to all reputation you've had, period.

There's two components that are tracked in "All", but not in "Year":

- The 1 reputation all users start with and can never lose. You never earned it, it's just a part of your account.
- The 100 bonus reputation from account association. This isn't tied to an event in time, it's tied to an account's existence. So even if you definitely associated this year, we don't store it as such.

Thus, most users who are shown will have either a 101 point or a 1 point discrepancy between "Year" and "All, depending on whether or not you had an account to associate when joining this site. The points you "earned this year" do not include these, and so they don't show up.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the prompt response! Oddly enough  it is making me wait 10 minutes to accept an answer, I have never seen this before, but I imagine is has to do with being a meta discussion. I'll get back to it :)